# std::stack.top() changes member (which is a pointer) of elements

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

During debugging the second execution of while loop the code below produces an `out_of_range` exception. I noticed that:

before stack.top():

[image]

after stack.top():

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

int replacement;
int toreplace;

class Node
{
public:
    int id_;
    std::vector<Node*> children;
    Node* at(int i)
    {
        return children.at(i);
    }
    std::vector<Node*> GetChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    Node(int id_) {
        this->id_ = id_;
    }
};

class CPreorderStackFrame
{
public:
    Node* node_;
    CPreorderStackFrame* root_;
    int index_;
    explicit CPreorderStackFrame(Node* node_, CPreorderStackFrame* root_, int index_)
    {
        this->node_ = node_;
        this->root_ = root_;
        this->index_ = index_;
    }
    void replaceChildrenByIndex(Node* replace, int index)
    {
        replace->id_ = node_->at(index)->id_;
        delete node_->GetChildren()[index];
        node_->GetChildren()[index] = replace;
    }
    bool hasChildren() {
        return !(node_->GetChildren().empty());
    }
};

void pre_order_traverse(Node* root,
    std::function<std::unique_ptr<Node>(Node*)> visit)
{ // always: root != NULL
    std::stack<CPreorderStackFrame> mystack;
    mystack.push(CPreorderStackFrame(root, NULL, NULL));
    while (!mystack.empty())
    {
        CPreorderStackFrame cur = mystack.top();
        mystack.pop();
        std::unique_ptr<Node> replace = visit(cur.node_);
        if (replace)
        {
            cur.root_->replaceChildrenByIndex(replace.release(), cur.index_);
        }
        else if (cur.hasChildren())
        {
            for (int i = cur.node_->GetChildren().size() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            { //preorder requires right to left
                Node *topush = cur.node_->at(i);
                if (topush)
                {
                    CPreorderStackFrame nextFrame(topush, &cur, i);
                    mystack.emplace(nextFrame); //hier ist noch alles richtig
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


std::unique_ptr<Node> print_visit(Node* node) {
    std::cout << node->id_ << ' ';
    return NULL;
}


std::unique_ptr<Node> replace_visit(Node* node) {
    std::cout << node->id_ << ' ';
    if (node->id_ == toreplace) {
        std::unique_ptr<Node> retval(new Node(replacement));
        return retval;
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main() {

    toreplace = 3;
    replacement = 8;

    Node *a = new Node(1);
    Node *b = new Node(2);
    Node *c = new Node(3);
    Node *d = new Node(4);
    Node *e = new Node(5);
    Node *f = new Node(3);
    Node *g = new Node(3);
    Node *h = new Node(42);
    Node *i = new Node(42);

    a->children.push_back(b);
    a->children.push_back(c);
    a->children.push_back(d);
    a->children.push_back(e);
    b->children.push_back(f);
    b->children.push_back(g);
    b->children.push_back(h);
    b->children.push_back(i);

    pre_order_traverse(a, replace_visit);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Study the return type of `GetChildren` carefully.

Comment: You have not finished your debugging yet. Construct a [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit what do you need to understand the question?

Comment: @molbdnilo GetChildren returns std::vector<Node*>. whats wrong with it? Why does it affect mystack.top()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is

```
std::vector<Node*> GetChildren()
```

which means that

```
delete node_->GetChildren()[index];
node_->GetChildren()[index] = replace;
```

is destroying an object, but only replacing its address in a copy of the vector.
Dereferencing that element in the original vector is undefined.

You need to return by reference, or move the removal code into `Node`.

Another problem, and the immediate cause of your observations, is that

```
CPreorderStackFrame nextFrame(topush, &cur, i);
mystack.emplace(nextFrame);
```

is storing a pointer to the automatic object `cur`, whose lifetime ends with the end of the iteration.
Dereferencing the pointer after that is undefined.

Most (probably all) compilers will reuse that object's storage for the next iteration, which means that all your `CPreorderStackFrame`s store the same pointer, and not a single one of them is valid by the time you dereference it.

It looks like the root doesn't need to be a pointer at all.